# Targeting a navigationBarItem's Action to a ControllerWrapper

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I've recently redone my app's main menu in SwiftUI. The modules were a mix of UIKit and SwiftUI so it added to the modernisation. I discovered that I could give the wrapper the decorations I needed from the main menu view with:

```
ClockMainViewControllerWrapper()
.navigationTitle("title")
.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
.navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: { print("foo") 
}, label: { 
  Image(systemName: "pencil")
}))
```

(I know navBarItems is deprecated)
What I'm looking for is how to target the print(foo) action into my ClockMainViewControllerWrapper.
My Clock when running as a ViewController, had a bar button that would fire off a transition in the ViewController, now I'm kind of stuck. Is this possible to target an action (the print foo) into the wrapper? I have a call in the ClockMainviewController that I want the Pencil Bar button to call.
-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, the answer was fairly simple.

From the menu in SwiftUI I post a notification and on the UIKit page that the menu opens I set up a listener and trigger the controller event.